# Update a table with the result of a store procedure actions over a column from the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table name resultado, that is created by calling and executing another stored procedures or functions. As a result a have a column that contains '1' and '0' as a vector like this '111100001'. Also I have a store procedured that count the numbers of 1 in the 'vector' as it follows.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[CharCount](@String VARCHAR(4000),@caracter VARCHAR(2))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @long INT
DECLARE @numeroveces INT =0
DECLARE @consecutivo INT =0
DECLARE @consecutivo1 INT =0
SET @numeroveces=0
SET @long=LEN(@String)

WHILE @long>=0
BEGIN
IF @caracter=SUBSTRING(@String,@long,1)
BEGIN
            set @numeroveces = @numeroveces + 1
            set @consecutivo = @consecutivo + 1
END
IF @caracter<>SUBSTRING(@String,@long,1) or (@long = 0)
BEGIN
    IF @consecutivo > @consecutivo1
        BEGIN
            set @consecutivo1 = @consecutivo
        END
  set @consecutivo = 0
END
SET @long=@long-1
END
SELECT @numeroveces
SELECT @consecutivo1
END
```

What I need is to execute the store procedure over a column from my table resultado and update the column with the result of the SP.

OriginalColumn--->SPResult---->UpdatedColumn

110111     --->         5    ---->        5

Comment: Do you want to run procedure to each value of OriginalColumn and update it?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this code? There doesn't seem to be a need for a loop here. It seems like maybe you are just counting the number of times a specific character is in a string?

Comment: @MegaTron Yes i want to run the procedure to each value of original columns.

Comment: This code is how i count i need to change it so I can aplly to all the values in a column

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure has 2 result sets the way you have it coded. Since in the example you posted here you are only trying to get the count of a given character I would strongly advise you to not use this procedure. It is horribly inefficient for such a simple task. This simple code will get the number of occurrences of a character without doing any looping. If you also need the longest consecutive count of occurrences there are better ways to do that too.

```
declare @String varchar(4000) = '111100001'
    , @caracter VARCHAR(2) = '1'

select LEN(@String) - LEN(Replace(@String, @caracter, ''))
```

Comment: Sean yes I need both results because for one column I will use the number of occurrences and to other columns the consecutive. Your solution is correct for the first case. I wll use in this project more stored procedures to update columns thats why Im looking forward to see how its done.

Comment: OK. I have to head to a meeting here in a few but I will check back in a couple hours and see what has happened. If nobody else helps you I will work out a non-looping approach to this for you.